# How to store graphs (from the igraph package) in R?

Tags: r, igraph

Is it possible to store a set of graphs (from `igraph`) in vector or other data structure?

I'm trying to do it in this way:

```
require('igraph')

g1 <- make_tree(10,3)
g2 <- make_tree(30,3)

gs <- c(g1,g2)

as.igraph(gs[1])
```

but it doesn't work. I got error:

```
Error in UseMethod("as.igraph") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.igraph' applied to an object of class "list"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store them in a list:

```
gs <- list(g1,g2)
class(gs[[1]])
# [1] "igraph"
```

The `gs[[i]]` are igraphs and you don't need to run `as.igraph` on them.

Also, according to the docs, the `as.igraph` function can only be used on `codeigraphHRG` objects.

Comment: What if this list is to be saved in a file? I tried using save(g,file="graph.Rdata"), but it didnt work.